# Necessito de auxílio com a linguagem PHP

Tags: php, select, if

Então galera estou com dificuldade em uma parte do meu código, como ele é muito grande irei postar só a parte que está com erro:

```
<?php
   try{
    $entrar = $_POST["entrar"];
    $cpf = $_POST["cpf"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    /*Conexão com o banco de dados*/
    $pdo = new pdo('tipo_do_banco:host=servidor;dbname=nome_do_banco','nome_do_usuário','senha_do_usuario');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    /*Verificando se o usuário existe na tabela já*/
    var_dump($entrar);
    if($entrar==true){
    $validacao = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE cpf = :cpf AND senha = :senha LIMIT 1');
    $validacao ->bindValue('nome'); (não sei se está certo, queria pegar o nome do cara da tabela sql)
    $validacao ->bindParam(":cpf",$cpf,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $validacao ->bindParam(":senha",$senha ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $validacao ->execute();
    /*Se a validação achar algo, vai direto para área do aluno*/
    $retorno = $validacao->FetchAll();
    if(count($retorno)>= 1){
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
        $_SESSION["cpf"] = $cpf;
        $_SESSION["senha"] = $senha;
        header('Location: alguma-area.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        unset ($_SESSION["cpf"]);
        unset ($_SESSION["senha"]);
        echo('Cpf ou senha inválidos');
    }
    }
    }catch(PDOException $error){
    echo 'Error: ' . $error->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Esse IF não executa, bloqueando todos os outros comandos (tem mais código).

Também gostaria de saber se é possível atráves desse select conseguir pegar o nome do cara da tabela certinho, como seria feito? Talvez usando `$validacao->bindValue('id');`

Comment: Logo antes da linha do if faça um var_dump($entrar) e poste aqui o resultado

Comment: Deu NULL quando fiz isso, porém estou passando normalmente. Olha isso... <input type="submit" id="entrar" name="entrar" value="Entrar"> $entrar = $_POST["entrar"]; var_dump($entrar);
     if($entrar==true){

Comment: Você declara $entrar em algum lugar? talvez inicialize ela com false!

Comment: Então está ai o problema.. edite a pergunta mostrando a parte do código em que você atribui um valor à variável $entrar

Comment: Sim, após o submit do formulário html, eu abro o <?php e declaro ela $entrar = $_POST["entrar"];

Comment: verifique se o input entrar do html está com o atributo name certinho.

Comment: crie um <input type="text" name="entrar" value="Entrar"> e apague o atributo name do botão, depois no PHP faça $entrar = isset($_POST['entrar'])

Comment: Bom, ele deu o valor bool (false, por não ter sido clicado), mas perdeu o submit para virar verdadeiro e enviar as informações...

Comment: Antes do if(count... coloca `print_r($validacao->errorInfo())`

Comment: Substituia `new pdo` por `new PDO`

Comment: -advantisaam, eu fiz isso, porém ele não entende a função if na hora de dar TRUE e não retorna erro nem nada

Comment: Antes dessa linha `$retorno = $validacao->FetchAll();` dê `print_r($validacao->errorInfo())`

Comment: Galera, obrigado pela ajuda, vou fechar o tópico =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudei algumas coisas que estavam erradas no seu código, tenta desta forma que eu coloquei abaixo.

```
<?php


//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $entrar = $_POST["entrar"];
    $cpf = filter_var($_POST["cpf"], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $senha = filter_var($_POST["senha"], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    try{
        $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=banco;port=3306','user','pass');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if(isset($cpf) && isset($senha)){
            $validacao = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE cpf = :cpf AND senha = :senha LIMIT 1');
            $validacao->bindParam(":cpf", $cpf, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
            $validacao->bindParam(":senha", $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
            $validacao->execute();
            $retorno = $validacao->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }catch(PDOException $error){
        echo 'Error: ' . $error->getMessage();
    }

    if(count($retorno) >= 1){
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $retorno['nome'];
        $_SESSION['cpf'] = $retorno['cpf'];
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $retorno['senha'];
        header('Location: alguma-area.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo('Cpf ou senha inválidos');
    }
}
?>
```